# Uploading a file with Swift 3 and Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am having difficulty getting the right Alamofire syntax to upload a file.  The server interface is a Rest API. I have a number of parameters I need to pass to hit the correct database and the specific record.
**Example:**

```
"https://ram23jtog.tt.rp.com/ewws/EWUpdate/.json?$KB=ITIL&$table=asset_table&$login=testuser2&$password=pwd123&$lang=en&id=18005&tdd_form=2017-5-8-911-6633442.pdf"
```

**One thing to note on the parameters is the "ID" parameter needs to be toward the end so that the table and login information is read first - or so it would appear.**

**I have tried to load the parameters up then append them later:**

```
        let parameters: Parameters = [

            "&tdd_form" : "test",
            "&id"       : "\(self.inventoryDeviceVal.recId!)",
            "$lang"     : "en",
            "$password" : "\(self.sharedDataVal.appUserPassword!)",
            "$login"    : "\(self.sharedDataVal.appUserID!)",
            "$table"    : "asset_table",
            "$KB"       : "ITIL"

        ]

        for (key, value) in parameters {
                    multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }
```

It looks to me like the parameters are getting truncated or there is an error that is preventing some of them from loading.

**Alamofire Request:**

```
        Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in


                for (key, value) in parameters {
                    multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
                }

                multipartFormData.append(fileURL, withName: fileName, fileName: fileName, mimeType: "application/pdf")

            }, to: updateCriteria) { (result) in

                    switch result {

                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.responseJSON { response in
                            //self.delegate?.showSuccessAlert()
                            print(response.request!)  // original URL request
                            print(response.response!) // URL response
                            print(response.data!)     // server data
                            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                            //                        self.showSuccesAlert()

                            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                            }
                        }

                    case .failure(let encodingError):
                        //self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
                        print(encodingError)
                }

            }


    }
```

Any Suggestions?  Would it be easier to do a simple Alamofire request instead of a multipart upload?

**RESOLUTION**

Reconfigured my parameters per Musa's suggestion:

```
  let parameters = [
        [
            "name"  : "$KB",
            "value" : "ITIL"
        ],
        [
            "name"  : "$table",
            "value" : "asset_table"
        ],
        [
            "name"  : "$login",
            "value" : "\(self.sharedDataVal.appUserID!)"
        ],
        [
            "name"  : "$password",
            "value" : "\(self.sharedDataVal.appUserPassword!)"
        ],
        [
            "name"  : "$lang",
            "value" : "en"
        ],
        [
            "name"  : "id",
            "value" : "\(self.inventoryDeviceVal.recId!)"
        ]

    ]
```

I had the parameter "tdd_form" up in the parameters definition.  I adjusted the append so that it is coded correctly with the "tdd_form" parameter in the right section now that the parameters were passing correctly.

```
        Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in


                for param in parameters  {
                    multipartFormData.append((param["value"]?.data(using: .utf8)!)!, withName: param["name"]!)
                }

                multipartFormData.append(fileURL, withName: "tdd_form", fileName: fileName, mimeType: "application/pdf")

            }, to: updateCriteria) { (result) in

                    switch result {

                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.responseJSON { response in
                            //self.delegate?.showSuccessAlert()
                            print(response.request!)  // original URL request
                            print(response.response!) // URL response
                            print(response.data!)     // server data
                            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                            //                        self.showSuccesAlert()

                            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                            }
                        }

                    case .failure(let encodingError):
                        //self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
                        print(encodingError)
                }

            }
```

Works perfectly!!

Comment: Personally I couldn't get the URL query parameters to work with MultipartFormData, so I'm not too sure. The way I solved it in my application was to build the URL with the query params myself, and then only append the file to the MultipartFormData and upload to that URL. Example: `multipartFormData.append(file, withName: "file")` and then the `to:` parameter on the `upload` method is `to: "\(url)?email=\(email)&type=\(type)"` but replace the query parameters with the ones you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it

```
    var parameters = [
        [
            "name": "tdd_form",
            "value": "test"
        ],
        [
            "name": "id",
            "value": "\(self.inventoryDeviceVal.recId!)"
        ]
          .
          .
          .
         etc
    ]

    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            //convert parameters to data
            for param in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append((param["value"]?.data(using: .utf8)!)!, withName: param["name"]!)
            }

            //Add the data

            //Mine was image , this is how I did it
            //let uuid = UUID().uuidString.lowercased()
            //multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "images[]", fileName: "\(uuid).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")

            multipartFormData.append(fileURL, withName: fileName, fileName: fileName, mimeType: "application/pdf")
    },
        to: updateCriteria){ (result) in

            switch result {

            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    //self.delegate?.showSuccessAlert()
                    print(response.request!)  // original URL request
                    print(response.response!) // URL response
                    print(response.data!)     // server data
                    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                    //                        self.showSuccesAlert()

                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                    }
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                //self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
                print(encodingError)
            }

    }
```

Comment: Musa, You were absolutely right with how you set up your parameters.  I had to massage some of those parameters for my own purpose, but it set me down the right path.  Been working on this for weeks.  I will post my changes so everyone can see.